# how to define condition statement in tensorflow?

Tags: python, if-statement, math, tensorflow

I have three functions in file fe_extraction.py

```
def rms_value(x):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x)))
def meanabs(x):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(x))

def req_value(x,y,Thersh):
    z = tf.cond(y>Thersh,rms_freq(x),peak_value(x))
return z
```

I want to simply apply a condition if y > thershold  perform rms_freq(x) or else peak_value(x) and return that value.
 y is the value obtained from another function.

```
# given values
# Thershold = 10.69 
# x is defined as tf.Variable , dtype tf.float64
# y = 45.34 obtained from function
....
z = fe_extraction.req_value(x,y,Thershold)
```

I get error as TypeError:fn1 must be callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rms_freq(x)` and `peak_value(x)` you're **calling** the function `rms_freq` and `peak_value` respectively,  passing `x` as argument.

Instead, you have to pass a callable or, in other words, a function, that `tf.cond` can execute.

Since you want `x` as a parameter for your functions, you can wrap them in a `lambda` that defines a callable object that captures the outside scope and thus sees the parameter `x`.

```
z = tf.cond(y>Thersh,lambda: rms_freq(x) ,lambda: peak_value(x))
```

Comment: it gives me an error again 
'TypeError: pred must not be a Python bool'

Comment: `y>Thersh` is a python boolean, this means that both `y` and  `Thersh` are python variables, so tf.cond is useless in this case, you can just use a python `if` statement. By the way, `cond` should be a tensorflow boolean, you must use tf operations like `tf.greater(y, Thersh, name=None)`